# SQLAlchemy SELECT confusion

Tags: sql, select, sqlalchemy

I'm going through [this SQLAlchemy tutorial](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/tutorial.html) and have become very confused by the following example (about halfway down the page):

```
>>> s = select([(users.c.fullname + ", " + addresses.c.email_address).label('title')],
...        and_(
...            users.c.id==addresses.c.user_id,
...            users.c.name.between('m', 'z'),
...           or_(
...              addresses.c.email_address.like('%@aol.com'),
...              addresses.c.email_address.like('%@msn.com')
...           )
...        )
...    )
>>> print conn.execute(s).fetchall() 
SELECT users.fullname || ? || addresses.email_address AS title
FROM users, addresses
WHERE users.id = addresses.user_id AND users.name BETWEEN ? AND ? AND
(addresses.email_address LIKE ? OR addresses.email_address LIKE ?)
(', ', 'm', 'z', '%@aol.com', '%@msn.com')
[(u'Wendy Williams, wendy@aol.com',)]
```

How does `(users.c.fullname + ", " + addresses.c.email_address)` identify columns to select from-- doesn't that mean it looks for columns titled `"fullname, email_address"`? I'm clearly misunderstanding something. The result `[(u'Wendy Williams, wendy@aol.com',)]` is the same format as the string given to SELECT.. I just don't understand how that works.

Never done databases before; I'm learning SQLAlchemy at the same time I'm learning SQL, so it's entirely possible my problem is with SQL not SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`users.c.fullname` is a clever object that overloads the `+` operator.  `users.c.fullname + ", "` creates a [`ClauseElement`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ClauseElement) representing the expression, which SQLAlchemy knows how to translate to any SQL engine's syntax.  Same reason you can do `users.c.name.between('m', 'z')`; `users.c.name` is an object with a `between` method that returns a `ClauseElement`.

Comment: yeah, so it seems to translate into `SELECT users.fullname || ', ' || addresses.email_address AS title ...`, and it says that '||' is the concatenate operator. so that means it searches for `"fullname, email_address"', right? which confuses me since none of the columns have that title

Comment: You're confusing strings with columns.  `users.fullname` isn't in quotes, so it's a column reference, using the value of `fullname` from the `users` table.  Look at the return value at the bottom of the example: it's a value from the `fullname` column, plus a literal comma and space, plus a value from the `email_address` column.